# Microsoft Word: numbering on headings not shown on level 1

Tags: microsoft-word, list

I would like to have something like this:

```
Chapter one
   1.1 Subchapter
      1.1.1 SubSubchapter
   1.2 Subchapter
Chapter two
   2.1 Subchapter
      2.1.1 SubSubchapter
   2.2 Subchapter
```

Notice, that the Level 1 of the list 'Chapter one' and 'Chapter two' have no numbering, but still the subchapters continue AS IF it was:

```
**1** Chapter one
       1.1 Subchapter
          1.1.1 SubSubchapter
       1.2 Subchapter
**2** Chapter two
       2.1 Subchapter
          2.1.1 SubSubchapter
       2.2 Subchapter
```

I just don't want numbering on the Level 1's, but also I want the numbering to continue down as if the Level 1's had numbering.

At all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just go into multilevel formatting and define the level as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was simple enough!